# TypeError: a is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I get the above error on the jQuery v1.7.2 code when I try to use the `$.each` method:

```
$.post('url_of_php_file.php',
            $.param( {

            }),
            function(data){
                $.each(data.articles, function(index, value){
                .....
});
```

The request returns:

```
{"articles": [
    {
        "id":"11",
        "date":"2012-12-19 15:52:06",
        "title":"url_title",
        "link":"url_link",
        "available":"1"
     },
    ..... *more rows like the above*
]}
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: I get it on firebug add-on for Firefox.
Seems that the 'a' is for the a in line 2 of  jQuery v1.7.2:
"(function(a,b)....."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something you did caused an error inside jQuery. This is 99.9% of the time a bug in your code and not a bug in jQuery.

What helps is using the development version of jQuery. It is not minified, which means that it still has the full variable names instead of `a`, `b`, etc.

Did you send a:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

before the `echo json_encode($data);`? That would triggers jQuery's JSON detection. Add a `console.log(data);` before the `$.each` to confirm the data looks like you'd expect.

Comment: what on earth can it be?
and where can I get this version?