# TypeError: a is undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I have created a JSON read function but I get error:

> TypeError: a is undefined

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
    var json = $.getJSON("http://localhost/stratagic-json/project_json.php", function() {
        console.log("success");
    });
    var mhtml = '';
    $.each(json.slider, function(key, val) {
        mhtml += '<li><div class="proj-details-wrap"> <img src="images/' + val.image + '" />';
        mhtml += '<div class="proj-badge">' + val.status + '</div>';
        mhtml += '<div class="proj-name">' + val.name + ' <span>' + val.location + '</span> </div>';
        mhtml += '</div>';
        mhtml += ' <div class="container proj-desc">' + val.description + '</div>';
        mhtml += '</li>';
    });
    var $ul = $('<ul class="slides">').append($(mhtml)); // append DOM only one time.
    $('.slider').append($ul);
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: a is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902782/typeerror-a-is-undefined)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous method and you're treating it synchronously. `json.slider` is `undefined` because `$.getJSON` actually returns a promise, not the data. The data needs to be accessed via the callback or a promise. This should work:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/stratagic-json/project_json.php", function(json) {
      var mhtml = '';
      $.each(json.slider, function(key, val) {
          mhtml += '<li><div class="proj-details-wrap"> <img src="images/' + val.image + '" />';
          mhtml += '<div class="proj-badge">' + val.status + '</div>';
          mhtml += '<div class="proj-name">' + val.name + ' <span>' + val.location + '</span> </div>';
          mhtml += '</div>';
          mhtml += ' <div class="container proj-desc">' + val.description + '</div>';
          mhtml += '</li>';
      });
      var $ul = $('<ul class="slides">').append($(mhtml)); // append DOM only one time.
      $('.slider').append($ul);
    });
})
```

You could also do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var jqXhr = $.getJSON("http://localhost/stratagic-json/project_json.php");
    jqXhr.done( function (data) {
      // Do something
    });
})
```